# ¿Es correcto decir "no te sé decir"?

Tags: gramática, verbos, pronombres, sintaxis

¿Es correcto decir "*no te sé decir*" o "*no te sabría decir*", en lugar de "*no sé decirte*" o "*no sabría decirte*"?

Comment: Una enfatiza al pronombre de objeto, otra, la acción; 1) *no te sé decir* (énfasis en el objeto indirecto). 2) *no sé decirte* (énfasis en la primera acción). Como ya se dijo, ambas son igual de correctas. (Se acostumbra mucho mover el pronombre de objeto en estas construcciones.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Según la RAE (énfasis añadido):

> [3. Colocación de los clíticos con respecto al verbo](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=elLl31yYnD65MTS9uF):
>
> c) Los clíticos se posponen a las formas simples de infinitivo y de gerundio: *Al mirarlo, sonrió*; *No conseguirás nada regañándome*. Pero **si el infinitivo o el gerundio forman parte de una perífrasis verbal, en la mayor parte de los casos los clíticos pueden colocarse también delante del verbo auxiliar de la perífrasis, que es el que aparece en forma personal:** *Debo hacerlo / Lo debo hacer; Tienes que llevárselo / Se lo tienes que llevar; Vais a arrepentiros / Os vais a arrepentir; Siempre está quejándose / Siempre se está quejando; Siguió explicándomelo / Me lo siguió explicando.*
>
> La anteposición de los clíticos no es posible cuando el verbo auxiliar de la perífrasis es impersonal: *Hay que pedírselo* (no * *Se lo hay que pedir*); o si el verbo en forma no personal es el sujeto oracional pospuesto de verbos como *parecer, importar, convenir*, etc.: *Parecía entenderlo* (no * *Lo parecía entender*); *Conviene intentarlo* (no * *Lo conviene intentar*); *Importa denunciarlo* (no * *Lo importa denunciar*). Tampoco es normal la anteposición de clíticos con verbos que expresan creencia, temor, deseo, preferencia o conocimiento, como *creer, temer, desear, preferir, negar, afirmar,* entre otros: *Cree haberlo guardado* (más normal que *Lo cree haber guardado*); *Prefiero ignorarte* (más normal que *Te prefiero ignorar*); *Deseo irme* (más normal que *Me deseo ir*); *Negó saberlo* (más normal que *Lo negó saber*), etc.

En conclusión, ambas formas son correctas y suenan igual de bien. Tal y como se explica en el link, la posposición del pronombre personal es normal en algunos casos, pero resulta poco natural o incorrecta en otros. Con el verbo "saber" en voz activa y en formas personales, no hay nada que impida tal colocación:

- No sé decirte = No te sé decir.
- No sé bajarme de la hamaca = No me sé bajar de la hamaca.

Comment: Agrego que ambas formas son usadas habitualmente.

Answer (score 1):

Todas son correctas:

No te sé decir = no sé decirte

Hay más casos que se pueden construir así:

No me sé controlar = no sé controlarme

Son correctas los cuatro ejemplos.